# The differences between JUnit 3 and JUnit 4

Tags: junit, junit4, junit3

Could someone describe in a few words what the main differences between JUnit 3 and 4 are?

Comment: This is not actually a question of opinion. There are very factual and explicit differences between Junit 3 and 4 and the enumeration of such is of interest.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

1. Java 5 annotations for setup and teardown (`@before` and `@after`)
   instead of `setUp()` and `tearDown()`.
2. don't need to extend TestCase anymore.
3. `@Test` annotation replaces `testSomeMethod()` naming convention.
4. `static imports` for asserts.
5. Junit theories, which allow you to separate data sets from the test
       itself.

Comment: Just came across this which may be interesting http://www.asjava.com/junit/junit-3-vs-junit-4-comparison/

Comment: can you give an example or a pointer to elaborate on the above point 5?

Comment: Refer this : http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html
and 
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjADahUKEwjugLOA87DHAhXDT44KHa4YCuM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.javacodegeeks.com%2F2013%2F12%2Fintroduction-to-junit-theories.html&ei=QzzSVa7THcOfuQSusaiYDg&usg=AFQjCNGab9k_SfHZgdih-g2gRIEH07THVw&sig2=S9IYicBahLQ0rBib7DrTdA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E

Comment: one more.. names doesn't need to start with "test" therefore pattern "testXXXXX" can be ignored with JUnit4.