# Is it possible to name a test suite in JUnit 4?

Tags: junit, junit4

In JUnit3, one would could name a test suite like this:

```
public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("Some test collection");
    suite.addTestSuite(TestX.class);
    return suite;
}
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in JUnit4?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thank you, I actually managed to get it working. My question was if there is a JUnit4 equivalent way of specifying the name/description of a test suite, like in JUnit3 with "Some test collection".

Some background:
I'm converting junit tests in legacy code to the version 4, and I don't want to lose any information if possible. I apologize, I should really have been more specific in the original question.

Comment: Isn't [`@RunWith(Suite.class)`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html) meant for exactly this purpose?

Comment: Yes, it's what I used. I just didn't find anyway to set the test suite name to a default string, like in JUnit 3. I've edited the question since in retrospective I was indeed overly vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `Suite` runner `@RunWith(Suite.class)`:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class, TestX.class})
public class MySuite {}
```

Where `Test1`, `Test2`, `TestX` contain your tests

ref. [RunWith](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html), [Suite](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html)

update:

WRT changing the actual description of your suite, I don't think there's a way to do it out-of-the-box (if there is I haven't seen it yet). What you can do, is to define your own runner with a custom description [update2]:

```
@RunWith(DescribedSuiteRunner.class)
@SuiteClasses({Test1.class, Test2.class, TestX.class})
@SuiteDescription("Some test collection")
public class MySuite {}

public class DescribedSuiteRunner extends Suite {
    // forward to Suite
    public DescribedSuiteRunner(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, builder);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return getTestClass()
                .getJavaClass()
                .getAnnotation(SuiteDescription.class)
                .value();
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface SuiteDescription {
    String value();
}
```

The default implementation of `getName` just returns the class being tested's name

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In JUnit 3.x, the JUnit methods had to be specifically named. They needed to begin with the word *test* in order for JUnit to run that as a test case. Now you can just use the `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test
public void thisIsMyTest() {
    // test goes here
}
```

Also in JUnit4 you can state if you want some tests to run *before* or *after* all the tests in this class are invoked:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Initializing...");
}

@After
public void finish() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Finishing...");
}
```

Further comparisons between JUnit3 and JUnit4 [here](http://www.asjava.com/junit/junit-3-vs-junit-4-comparison/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685730/the-differences-between-junit-3-and-junit-4).

Edit: after blgt's comment, I see I might have misunderstood your intent.
You *are* probably looking for `@RunWith(Suite.class)` - When a class is annotated with `@RunWith`, JUnit will invoke the class in which is annotated so as to run the tests, instead of using the runner built into JUnit. Full example of usage is [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-runwith-example/), tl;dr below:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ FirstTest.class, SecondTest.class })
public class AllTests {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I what I meant was trying to find a way to name the test suite itself, like in the example. Sorry, I've edited the question above.